# how to create viewcontroller for ipad in ios Aplication?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am working on a iPad Application.
My target is set to Ipad.

in Storyboard when i add new view controller.i am not able to add Size for ipad like iPad Full Size etc.issue is attached in Screenshot.
Choose `Size` from Xcode's **Attributes Inspector** is showing `Invalid value`.

Please Help me to find out an issue.

[image]

Comment: are you using size class ??

Comment: No.  not size class

Comment: Change the device to iPhone in deployment info and again change it to iPad.

Answer (score 0):

while u create the project make sure you have selected Universal option for the Devices. [image: Check here]

Comment: Universal is not the correct target if they want iPad only.

Comment: i have choosen ipad only

Comment: it was working till yesterday. suddenly its stopped working

Comment: Yes you can change the target

Comment: i am getting option of iphone only.not of ipad